# FindBugs new Formula

Tags: java, eclipse, static-analysis, findbugs

I often do this kind of mistake, instead of:

```
Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.string_id), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

i do this:

```
Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.string_id), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

I think, this should be detectable with FindBugs (or any other static analysis utility), which I currently use with Eclipse.

**Conditions:**

- static call
- we don't save the returned value

**Message similar to:**

> You apparently forgot to save returned value of call, or you're missing `.show()` call on returned Toast variable

This message is strictly localized to this type of mistake, but it could contain more conditions or this can be some common mistake.

But what I do miss, is some tutorial, how can we add new recipes to FindBugs database. Can you please point me to place I haven't found in my search or offer me another solution for finding this kind of problem?

Comment: http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/AddingDetectors.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I can see two links that can help you:

- [FindBugs, Part 2: Writing custom detectors](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-findbug2/)
- [Adding Detectors](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/AddingDetectors.txt) from FindBugs sources

The former qualifies as a tutorial, I guess.